# How to change modelAttribute of a form from jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

Am developing a application using HTML5 and Spring MVC.

A table is displayed initially and on clicking a row, a form should be populated as dialog with that specific datas of the row filled in form attributes.

So what i need actually is on clicking that row modelArrtibute of that form should be set from jquery or javascript.

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form:label path="smtpServer" for="serialNumber"
                                class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2 control-label">SMTP Server</form:label >
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <form:input path="smtpServer" type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNumber" name="smtpserver"
                                    placeholder="SMTP Server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form:label path="portNumber" for="serialNumber"
                                class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2 control-label">Port
                                Number</form:label >
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <form:input path="portNumber" type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNumber"
                                    placeholder="Port Number" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-4">
                            <p>
                            <h5>
                                <form:checkbox path="issmtpEnabled" value="1"/>Enable SMTP Authentication
                            </h5>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form:label path="fromAddress" for="serialNumber"
                                class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2 control-label">From
                                Email Address</form:label >
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <form:input path="fromAddress" type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNumber"
                                    placeholder="From Email Address" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply" />
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
```

TABLE

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th>SMTP Server</th>
            <th>Port Number</th>
            <th>Sender Email</th>                                               
            <th>Use SSL/TLS Secure Connection</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="PT"
            items="${alertSettingsManagement.emailSettingsAlertList}">
            <tr id="${PT.id}" class="emailSettingsRow">
                <td>${PT.smtpServer}</td>
                <td>${PT.portNumber}</td>
                <td>${PT.fromAddress}</td>                                                  
                <td>${PT.issslEnabled == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</td>                                                 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.emailSettingsRow').click( function() {
                   //want to set modelAttribute here
          var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();          
          $('#emailModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: Why do you think you can set a JSP tag attribute with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change modelAttribute of a spring  tag.

Why because at the time of the rendering the response spring's  tag will be converted as normal  tag in HTML, and it will not contain modelAttribute any more, modelAttribute will be converted as name and id (i.e. name of modelAttribute will be given to both name and id attributes in the HTML form tag).